Fast method to find a linear map satisfying given conditions.
Find a linear map $T(\vec{x}):\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:
$$
T(\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad T(\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 4 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

We know $T(\vec{x})$ can be written as $A\vec{x}$ with:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}
$$
We now have 6 unknowns and 4 equations, so I decided to set $c=f=0$ (doing something like $e=f=0$ doesn't work) and then solved for $a, b, d, e$.
It worked but is there a faster way?

As you said, you get 4 equations in 6 unknowns. Either these equations are consistent and admit infinitely many solutions, or inconsistent and you have no solution. You don't need to (and shouldn't ) decide that two variables are zero.

@Medo Yes but the question is that one should just find one $f$ not all of them.

Treat it as two uncoupled systems, each having 2 equations and 3 unknowns

The system involving $a, b, c$ is...
$$ 2a-b+5c=-4  \\ 10a+4b-2c=1$$
The complete solution typically parametrizes two of the variables in terms of the third, which can be any real number. If you just want one solution you can choose any of the 3 variables to have any real value, and then compute the other 2. Choosing $c=0$ is a pretty good choice, but I think $c=-\frac 45$ is a little faster...
$$c=-\frac 45 \implies b=2a\implies 18a=-\frac 35$$
$$c=-\frac 45 \implies b=-\frac 2{30}, \; a=-\frac 1{30}$$
The other system is...
$$ 2d-e+5f=-1  \\ 10d+4e-2f=2$$
So ...
$$f=-\frac 15 \implies e=2d\implies 18d=\frac {8}5$$
$$f=-\frac 15 \implies e=\frac {8}{45},\; d=\frac {4}{45}$$
